# Brightly lit enviroment

Tags: lens

Which lenses should be used on small format DSLR camera with full size 35mm sensor to photograph a bride at 10am in a brightly lit enviroment

Comment: The ones you have in your case/bag.

Comment: Hi, Nita. Do you talk about outdoors or indoors?

Comment: What is a "small format DSLR camera with full size 35mm sensor?" that distinguishes it from any other "full frame" DSLR camera?

Answer (score 1):

The lens does not care how light or how dark it is, it simply lets light pass through it to the camera's sensor or film. **You** control how little or how much light is passed though the lens by setting the F stop ( *f stop is the aperture or size of the opening in the lens* ) and the shutter speed,( *the amount of time the shutter is open and letting light into the cameras sensor or film* ).

You can use any lens you have or want to rent as long as you set the camera properly to achieve the correct exposure for the amount of light available.

ISO is a setting on your camera that lets you set how sensitive the sensor is. In brightly lit scene's you set it to lower number and as it gets darker you may need to set to a higher number in order to let enough light pass through the lens and shutter to achieve proper exposure. It is best practice use the lowest ISO you can in order to achieve proper exposure because the higher the ISO setting the more digital noise is recorded to the photo/file.

F stop/aperture and shutter speed control the **amount** of light let into the camera and onto the sensor or film and ISO is how **sensitive** the camera's sensor is. ( film comes in specific ISO's.)

Set your cameras ISO to 100 ( *for bright sunlight* ) or 200 (*if it is a *little* cloudy* ) and then Use your light meter to measure the light. Set your  camera to the  F stop and shutter speed that the camera's light meter tells you will give a proper exposure. Take a test shot, the white dress my be a little to bright so adjust your exposure by increasing the shutter speed ( *faster, thereby reducing the amount of light entering the camera* ) and do another test.

This is a very basic explanation and I would suggest that before you take such an important photo that you do some research, get a good book about cameras and photography so you are prepared with the knowledge you need to take what might be one of the most important photos of woman's life.

DO SOME TEST SHOOTS.